# Duplicate code due to different list objects

Tags: kotlin

So I got a function in each of my classes which does the same but with diffrent objects in the list, for example I got the methode for Streets and HouseNumbers.

Here the example of the two nearly identical functions, first for Streets:

```
fun batchInsert(import: List<ImportStreet>, source: String) {
    var part : MutableList<ImportStreet> = mutableListOf()

    for(i in import)
    {
        part.add(i)
        if(part.size % 25000 == 0)
        {
            batchUpdate(part, source)
            part = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    if (part.size < 25000) {
        batchUpdate(part, source)
    }
}
```

Nearly the same but now for HouseNumbers:

```
fun batchInsert(import: List<ImportHouseNumber>, source: String) {
    var part : MutableList<ImportHouseNumber> = mutableListOf()

    for(i in import)
    {
        part.add(i)
        if(part.size % 25000 == 0)
        {
            batchUpdate(part, source)
            part = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    if (part.size < 25000) {
        batchUpdate(part, source)
    }
}
```

Is there a easy or efficent way to get rid of the duplicate code?

Comment: You should be able to find what you need here: [Kotlin Generics Docs - generic functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Kotlin Generics - generic functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions), we can create a single function that will work with both of your classes. Any class actually, as long as we are not looking to access class specific functions.

```
fun <T> batchInsert(import: List<T>, source: String) {
    var part: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
    
    for (i in import) {
        part.add(i)
        if (part.size % 25000 == 0) {
            batchUpdate(part, source)
            part = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    if (part.size < 25000) {
        batchUpdate(part, source)
    }
    
}
```

I don't know what your `batchUpdate` fun does, or how it does it, but it can similarly be changed in the same manner:

```
fun <T> batchUpdate(batch: List<T>, source: String) {
    //I don't know what this function does
}
```

We could also take advantage of [Kotlin's chunked function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) and make the whole process a bit more efficient (we don't need to create a new list ourselfs).

```
fun <T> batchInsert(import: List<T>, source: String) {
    import
        .chunked(25000)
        .forEach { currentBatch ->
            batchUpdate(currentBatch, source)
        }
}
```

Another "trick" that we can use would be to make the fun a [Kotlin extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) (note it doesn't always make sense to use this, it depends on the rest of the project, I'll recommend that you read the docs from the link)

```
fun <T> List<T>.batchInsert(source:String){
    chunked(25000)
        .forEach { currentBatch ->
            batchUpdate(currentBatch, source)
        }
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf<ImportHouseNumber>() //empty list just to show how the extension works
    val secondList = listOf<ImportStreet>() //empty list just to show how the extension works
    val source = "source"
    
    list.batchInsert(source)
    secondList.batchInsert(source)
}
```

---

A quick and dirty solution for the case when `batchUpdate` can't be a generic (see comments), would be to still have a generic fun between them that will reroute each class into a different direction. Something like this:

```
fun <T> batchUpdate(batch: List<T>, source: String) {
    val first = batch.firstOrNull() ?: return
    
    when (first) {
        is ImportStreet -> { /* do stuff with the batch and source */ }
        is ImportHouseNumber -> { /* do stuff with the batch and source */ }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not a big fan of doing things like this, and it is a code smell. But in some cases it is enough to get through an issue. If anybody else has other ideas please advise.

Comment: in the case of my project I use class specific functions in batchUpdate, is there a way to implement batchInsert with generics then ? or is it not possible

Comment: @DavidTinhofer I'll add a quick and dirty solution to the answer itself.